# CodeIgniter website + phonegap practice

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, codeigniter, cordova

I have already developed website using codeigniter and it's now in testing phase and as business requirement we need to have a small version with limited feature as mobile app Iphone, Android...etc

I have done small research and i found that one the best practices so far is using RESTFUL webservice in codeigniter so i wont rewrite the code i just add API that handle request from PhoneGAP app

but I mnot sure how i will be able to communicate from phonegap , is it JAVASCRIPT like Node.js or what kind of code supported in PhoneGAP,

Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: A Phonegap application *is* a Web application, held inside of a native app. The native app simply creates a Web view and exposes a JavaScript API for accessing device hardware. The really "heavy lifting" of the app happens inside that Web view, using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, just like in a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make AJAX requests in PhoneGap in a similar manner like you would in a browser application. I haven't worked with node.js in any respect so I can't comment on that specific library but I have used both jQuery and Dojo to perform AJAX requests. You will just want to make sure your application has asked for the proper permissions to make network requests to your domain. Have a look at this for setting up those permissions.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: thank you for your comment i think i will do this in my next project but for this one i just need simple app wrapping so i will go with @ apsillers method

Comment: @AhmedSamy I'm glad you found my comment helpful, but make sure you look at the link in Nick's answer -- without it, your Phonegap app might not be able to reach your server on certain platforms.